# register variable in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I know the concept of register variable and it's use cases but there are few questions in my mind based on what I have tried.

1. I cannot access the address of a register variable in C though I can do it C++! Why? Is there any issue in accessing the addressing of a register variable?
2. Suppose if I declare a string variable in C++ as register, then where will that variable be stored? What is the point in declaring the storage class of non-numeric data types such as 'string' in C++ to be register??

**UPDATE:**
I thought that C++ allows us to fetch the address of a register variable, as I was not getting any error in my program which is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

clock_t beg, en;

int main(){

    int j, k=0;

    beg=clock();
    for(register int i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        /*if(k==0){
            cout<<&i<<endl;    // if this code is uncommented, then C++ rejects the recommendation to make 'i' as register
            k++;
        }*/
    }
    en=clock();

    cout<<en-beg<<endl;

    cout<<&j<<endl<<&k;

    return 0;
}
```

What I have observed is, if I make the variable 'i' as register and don't try to print the address using '&i' then C++ accepts the recommendation and stores 'i' in register, this can be infered from running time of for loop which will always be around 4-12 ms if 'i' is in register. But if I try to print address of variable 'i' then though I don't get any error but C++ rejects the recommendation and this can be infered from the time of execution of loop which is always more than 25 if i is not register!!

So, basically I cannot fetch address of a variable with storage class as register!! WHY?

Comment: See this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908835/c-c-register-variable.  C++ treats `register` as a hint and may ignore it; C can do the same, although compilers like GCC will complain if you go after the address of a variable declared as a `register`.

Comment: @Blrfl: I don't think that answers my question! Moreover I have found something interesting, I'll edit my question, have a look.

Comment: The attribute `register` was actually a hint from the programmer to the compiler back in the old days, which variables he wants to put into registers to speed up execution.

Comment: The top-voted answer in the question I linked to has quotes from the C99 and C++11 standards that should answer it.  C++ has deprecated `register` but will ignore it if its address is used within the variable's scope.  C allows the compiler to decide how to deal with it.  GCC happens to complain about it, others may or may not.  Ratchet freak's answer here pretty much covers the rest.

Comment: A register has no address.  It is not part of main memory.

Comment: -1: pet peeve of mine: Trying 'it' on 'your' compiler is no substitute to reading the language specification, and a very poor way to definitively understand what the language construct should do.

Comment: +1 for asking clarification after you saw results you couldn't understand.

Comment: Are you sure your difference in loop time wasn't because of the extra print call?

Answer (score 12):

The variables of a program (on modern non-embedded architectures) can live in one of 2 places, the RAM and the registers. The RAM is indexed and registers can be accessed directly in the opcodes.

The address of a variable is the index where it lives in the RAM, a register doesn't live in the RAM so there is no way to create a meaningful address for it unless you put it on the stack but that defeats the purpose of the `register` keyword.

As fun as the keyword is, these days compilers are good enough to decide for themselves which variables never need to get copied on the stack or not (the sub branch there is called [register allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation)).

And as with most old school optimizations giving hints to the optimizer is more likely to confuse and/or hinder it if you don't know exactly what the results are. Because optimizers are geared towards the idiomatic language constructs, and unless there is a bottle neck in the function don't worry about it. Don't shave off 1 or 2 cycles of a rarely used function when the true bottle neck is the DB access.